# Parameterize ADF Global Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

We wanted to parameterise the Global Parameters in the Azure Data Factory and apply transformation in the Azure DevOps Deployment pipeline. We followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters#cicd, but it's not providing the intended results.

Following are the global parameters that we wanted to parameterise.
[image] and this tutorial - https://medium.com/@diangermishuizen/global-parameters-101-in-azure-data-factory-9f88477a52a

The global parameters are under the "factory" folder. Therefore, we expected it to create a parameters file similar to "ARMTemplateParamteresForFactory.json" or add the global parameters.
[image]

Any help to parameterise the global parameters is much appreciated.